# Add active class to nav menu on click of link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jsp

I am developing a web page wherein I have header(containing the navigational menu) in separate html file say reusableheader.html and footer in separate file i.e. reusablefooter.html.

reusableheader.html:

```
<style>
.nav-menu a:hover, .nav-menu .active > a, .nav-menu li:hover > a {
  color: #3fbbc0;
  border-color: #3fbbc0;
}
</style>

<script>
         $(function(){
          var current_page_URL = location.href;
          $( "a" ).each(function() 
          {
             if ($(this).attr("href") !== "#") 
             {
               var target_URL = $(this).prop("href");
               if (target_URL == current_page_URL) 
               {
                  $("a").parent("li").removeClass("active");
                  $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
                  return false;
               }
             }
          });
        });   
</script> 

<nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block"> //set to fixed-top.
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="/hospital/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="/hospital/aboutus">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="/hospital/services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="/hospital/departments">Departments</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="/hospital/doctors">Doctors</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reach Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="/hospital/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Feedback</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Blogs</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Newsletters</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```

I am including the below javascript code in all my other web pages:

otherpages.jsp

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#header").load("reusableheader.html");
     });
</script>
```

The above code works fine i.e. on click of link on the menu item, its becomes the active link with the color assigned(in css) but when I scroll the page down, the activeness shifts from currently active link back to the "home" link.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi , is there any other code responsible for this ? Because your active class will get call only onces ..

Comment: Hi Swati, I did not understand your question. Kindly explain clearly. I am not that good at javascript. The above code is all and I don't think any other code is causing it. Thanks.

Comment: As you said `when I scroll the page down, the activeness shifts from currently active link back to the "home" link..` ? This should not happen ..there might be some other code which might be doing this or if you create demo code for above issue it would good .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with removing the `active` class on the `li` element. How can you say `$("a").parent("li").removeClass("active");` when you have got so many `a` elements with parent `li` element.

Instead, create a new for loop function which removes the element if the `active` class is found regardless of wherever it is in the list. And also add the logic on the click event of the `li` element, otherwise, it keeps looking for a URL match and changes it and would behave oddly if any path gets appended to the URL.

```
function removeClass() {
    var listItems = $(".nav-menu > ul > li");
    listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
        $(li).removeClass("active");
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried the above solution but still not working. I created the above method and called it on the onclick event of <li>. Maybe, I may not have understood your solution correctly hence was unable to get it working. I don't work on javascript much.